# After osm2pgrouting disappeared street segments

Tags: postgresql, gis, openstreetmap, postgis, pgrouting

I'm download osm-file with some city. In QGIS this map looks good, all streets is connected. Next, i execute osm2pgrouting and in QGIS (when i connect to postgres db) i watch map without some segments in street. Therefore, find path not worked (i think so). Because of what the problem is and how to solve it?
And more, after i executed osm2pgrouting in QGIS i watch many lines from what that point (like sun, extensively). I'm define coordinates of point and delete all ways with this coordinates.

UPDATE. I'm download two maps. First map is contain town (Russia, Krasnoyarsk) and i got it from openstreetmap.org, chosen area and export it. Second map contain region. I got it from some gis-site, but i forgot the address. Unfortunately I can not post a picture for an example. In map in postgress missing half segments of all. Some hightways segments is missing, but some is not.

UPDATE2. I have osm2pgrouting log:

```
Trying to load data
Trying to parse data
Reference nd=1162932299 has no corresponding Node Entry (Maybe Node entry after Reference?)
Reference nd=1162931037 has no corresponding Node Entry (Maybe Node entry after Reference?)
...
Split ways
Dropping tables...
Creating tables...
Nodes table created
2create ways failed: 
Types table created
Way_tag table created
Relations table created
Relation_ways table created
Classes table created
Adding tag types and classes to database...
Adding relations to database...
Adding nodes to database...
Adding ways to database...
Creating topology...
size of streets: 62931
size of splitted ways : 97921
finished
```

And i use with osm2pgrouting standart mapconfig.xml.
I noticed that line from the some point and the other end is at the beginning of the missing segment. I think, means that this line is missing segments. But osm file open in QGIS and is correct.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details. Where did you download the map exactly? Which segments are missing and which not? Can you show an example?

Comment: Thank you to pay attention to my question. Please see UPDATE.

Comment: According to the log there is a problem with [node 1162932299](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1162931037) and [node 1162931037](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1162931037) but they are only part of a power line and don't belong to a street. The log has a *create ways failed:* message, is there no further log message after the colon?

Comment: No, message is missing.

Comment: I avoided a problem by osm2po converter.